# Using getsockopt to check the initial value of SO_DEBUG option

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

I am trying to understand the nature of `getsockopt(int s, int level, int optname, void *optval, socklen_t *optlen)`.
I am trying to see the initial status of `SO_DEBUG` and I am referring to this link https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/getsockopt.3.asp , and I am not sure if I am doing this the correct way because I am getting random values.

```
    //***********************************************Libraries****************************************************************
    #include <iostream>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    using namespace std;
    //************************************************************************************************************************

    int main()
    {

            int * optval;

            int optionDebug = 0;
            socklen_t  optlen;
            int sockFD;
            sockFD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM ,0);

            optlen =sizeof(optval);

            int udpFD;
            udpFD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM,0);

            optionDebug = getsockopt(sockFD, SOL_SOCKET, SO_DEBUG, optval, &optlen) ;

            cout<<"My value "<< *optval<<endl;

            return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To retrieve the value for `optval` you need to pass the address of a valid variable (not an uninitialized pointer):

```
   ExpectedOptType optval;
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Put whatever type (probably a enum) is expected for
//                 the specific option
   optionDebug = getsockopt(sockFD, SOL_SOCKET, SO_DEBUG, &optval, &optlen);
                                                       // ^
```

Read more details about how it works here: [`getsockopt(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsockopt.2.html).

Comment: I did the correction above and the  output of my program was 0. Does it mean that the SO_DEBUG  option was set to false initially when I created my socket.

Comment: @Swornim1 Probably yes. Try to re-read the value after applying `setsockopt()`.

Comment: I am getting 0 for any option I am asking for (e.g., SO_RCVBUF) and optlen is also 0. Any clues why is that?

Comment: If I load optlen with sizeof(int) I get a value of 163840 for SO_RCVBUF but if I check /proc/sys/net/ipv4/udp_mem (or any of these similar files) I get nothing close to that...

Comment: OK, I found out. The file I should have checked is /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_default